Which episode of WWF:RAW was this from?
I remember seeing this sometime during the late 90s (or possibly early 2000s)  
The WWE was known as WWF (World Wrestling Federation) back then and this was a segment on their RAW program 
It wasn't a wrestling match but one of the funny segments they did between matches, and it was a build up to a main event match in one of the monthly special events that WWF used to do (the special event was not Wrestlemania as far as I remember) 
The main event was supposed to be a 4-way match between Big Show, Triple H, Rock and Mankind (Mick Foley had his Mankind character at that time). Shane McMahon had sided with Big Show, and he got 3 other people to dress up as Triple H, Rock and Mankind and got them into the ring. Then he called out the Big Show who came to the ring and beat up all the other three. This was supposed to be a taunt to the real Triple H, Rock and Mankind, and Shane was showing them what Big Show would do to them in the actual main event match.  
This is as much as I remember from that segment. I have been looking online for a clip of this segment but I've never been able to find one. I'm hoping if someone can identify which particular episode of RAW this was from, I will be able to find a clip. This might have been a part of their Smackdown program but I'm not sure, I'm more leaning towards it being a part of RAW. I think one more gimmick of the 4-way match main event was that each one of the wrestlers had one of the members of the McMahon family at their side, with Shane siding with the Big Show.
Please help me identify this episode.

Sounds like a lead up to WM16 in 2000

It would have to be WM16; Foley retired after WM16 for many years, by the time he came back I think Rock had left. But I don't see anything on the Raw or Smackdown summaries leading up to that.

@kutulumike: did he have mankind persona before he retired? I thought he wasn't wearing a mask at that time, that's why I said the event probably wasn't WM in the question

He was Cactus Jack before he retired; but when he came back to do WM that year, he came back as Mankind. That puts a pretty short window on when it could be, Feb/Mar/April of 2000. I should be able to scan through the shows on the network and see.

I can't seem to find that Raw either, but i do remember it as well. It aired two weeks before Wrestlemania 2000 (16). It was a mock match between the Big Show, and three people who dressed up like Triple H, The Rock and Mankind.

This was from the March 23, 2000 episode of SmackDown.  The men dressed up as Triple H, the Rock, and Mankind were the Mean Street Posse.





wow this is it, thanks a lot. Is a clip of this available anywhere?

@user13267 remember to mark this answer correct if you feel it is...
